# vue-splide only works in Nuxt dev environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, splidejs

I am having issues trying to make [vue-splide](https://splidejs.com/integration-vue-splide/) work outside of `nuxt dev`, after generating the static or the spa, it doesn't work properly.

Changing the target in `nuxt.config.js` from `static` to `SPA` doesn't solve the problem.
Instead of using `nuxt generate` I also tried `nuxt build` and the results are the same.

The two pictures are here:

[image]

[image]

The slider is working only in one of them, as it can be seen.

Any help on making it work properly so I can deploy the site?

`nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Visgrow Internships',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'preconnect', href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,500;1,300;2,100&display=swap' },
    ],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/splide.client.js', ssr: false }],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {},
}
```

`splide.client.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueSplide from '@splidejs/vue-splide';
// import '@splidejs/splide/dist/css/splide.min.css';
// Importing the original CSS does not change a thing. Also, I import the above CSS in the bellow css
import '../plugins-css/splide.css';


Vue.use(VueSplide);
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it on my side, working perfectly fine.

Install the package with either `yarn` or `npm`.

```
yarn add @splidejs/vue-splide
```

Setup the plugin [in the usual way](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/).

`vue-splide.client.js`

```js
import VueSplide from '@splidejs/vue-splide'
import Vue from 'vue'
import '@splidejs/splide/dist/css/themes/splide-sea-green.min.css'

Vue.use(VueSplide)
```

Import the plugin in `plugins`, no need to use `ssr: false` (it actually does not exist anymore) nor [`mode`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/#object-syntax) since you went to suffix the file with `client.js`.

```js
export default {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
  plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-splide.client.js'],
  ...
}
```

Then, using it in a view is perfectly fine, styling aside.

`pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <splide class="custom">
      <splide-slide>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?water" />
      </splide-slide>
      <splide-slide>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?fire" />
      </splide-slide>
      <splide-slide>
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?earth" />
      </splide-slide>
    </splide>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.splide__slide {
  height: 50vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.custom {
  height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
}
</style>
```

For the project, I went with `ssr: false` and `target: 'static'` (PS: `target: SPA` [does not exist](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-target)) so, I then need to do

```
yarn generate
yarn start
```

And here is the result
[image]

Comment: I added this line "ssr: false," to my nuxt.config.js and that solved the problem!
Not sure why it was not there in the first place. Thanks for you help!!!

Comment: It depends on the events that you have chosen during the Nuxt app creation.